# iOS detect user movement without GPS

Tags: ios, gyroscope

Is it possible to detect user movement via gyroscope? In general I need to calculate user's movement without GPS. I don't need to know user coordinates just something like this - 100 meters straight, turn left, 50 meters straight ect.

Answer (score 0):

A gyroscrope measures changes in spatial *orientation*. Thus it can't tell you how far the user travelled. It can't even tell you if the user has turned right, since if the user also rotates the device left, you'll learn nothing.